# PHP loop through array and check dates

Tags: php, json, date, loops

I have a form in my app. This form consists of 2 textfields type='date'. Now, when two dates are given, the dates are send to a PHP-script that translates the dates with strtotime.

The PHP-script makes a connection to a mySQL database that returns a result with requests. I would like to loop through all requests and check if the date of the request is BETWEEN the two dates that where sent by the form.

**What happens now:**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Requests";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if($result) {

foreach ($result as $row){
    $return[]=array('employeeid'=>$row['employeeid']
                    'id'=>$row['id'],
                    'startdate'=>$row['startdate'],
                    'enddate'=>$row['enddate'],
                    'type'=>$row['type'],
                    'reason'=>$row['reason']);
}

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo '' . json_encode($return) .'';
return true;

} else {
    return false;
}
```

The code above generates a perfect json-file with the requests. But as I mentioned I would like to check whether the startdate of the requests above is between the two dates that are send by the form.

**Something like this:**

```
if (($request_startdate >= $startdate) && ($request_startdate <= $enddate)) {
  //generate array with the requests
} else {
  //no requests between dates. 
}
```

But how to loop through the requests and check the startdate?

Thanks in advance.

Jan

Comment: Dont do that, use the database, thats exactly what it is for: `SELECT * FROM Requests WHERE startdate < ? and enddate > ?` (you will need the correct syntax for including the actual variables)

Comment: You're already looping through the requests with your foreach to process the database results - so you can do the very check you have outlined in that loop. However as Steve mentioned, it would usually make more sense to do it in your SELECT statement. Otherwise you will pull every record in the database each time you process the form.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking the hard way, it's easier to add a where statment to your select query:

I assume that your form have two fields named date1, date2

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Requests where startdate>:date1 and enddate<:date2";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':date1',$_POST['date1'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':date2',$_POST['date2'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert your string inputs to DateTime and format it to [ISO date format](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) (or at least make sure they are in a format that mySQL accepts)

```
$sdt = DateTime::createFromFormat('format of your input', $request_startdate);
$edt = DateTime::createFromFormat('format of your input', $request_enddate);
```

Modify your sql to query only the rows that you want to use:

```
SELECT * FROM Requests 
WHERE startdate <= :sdt AND :edt >= :edt
```

Then bind your parameters ([see php doc](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)):

```
$stmt->bindParam(':sdt', $sdt->format('YYYY-mm-dd 00:00:00'), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':edt', $edt->format('YYYY-mm-dd 23:59:59'), PDO::PARAM_STR);
```